# no match for operator C++ when it is already defined

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I am writing a program that involves the use of complex numbers so I have defined a complex number class which has overloaded operators for the operations that one can have. They have worked in the use of other functions and prior tests of them yet for one of my functions i get the following error code:

```
||=== Build: Debug in complex (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/gagler/c_stuff/complex/polynomials.h||In function ‘Comp f(Comp*, int, Comp)’:|
/home/gagler/c_stuff/complex/polynomials.h|81|error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘Comp’ and ‘Comp’)|
/home/gagler/c_stuff/complex/polynomials.h|81|note: candidates are:|
/home/gagler/c_stuff/complex/complex.h|60|note: Comp Comp::operator*(double)|
/home/gagler/c_stuff/complex/complex.h|60|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Comp’ to ‘double’|
/home/gagler/c_stuff/complex/complex.h|68|note: Comp Comp::operator*(Comp&)|
/home/gagler/c_stuff/complex/complex.h|68|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Comp’ to ‘Comp&’|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

There clearly is an operator defined in my header which takes operands of Comp and Comp. Comp being the class that i had defined.
Here is the header file with the operator definitions:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

#define PI 3.1415926535
#include <math.h>
#include "combinatorics.h"

double abs(double num){
    return (num < 0) ? num * -1 : num;
}

class Comp{
public:
    double re;//Re(z)
    double im;//Im(z)
    Comp(double a, double b){
        re = a;
        im = b;
    }
    Comp(){
        re = 0;
        im = 0;
    }

    double arg(){
        double theta = atan(abs(im) / abs(re));
        if(re < 0){
            theta = PI - theta;
        }
        if(im < 0){
            theta *= -1;
        }
        return theta;
    }

    double mod(){
        return sqrt( re * re + im * im);
    }

    Comp conj(){
        Comp z1(re, im*-1);
        return z1;
    }

    Comp operator+(double a){
        Comp z(this->re + a,  this->im);
        return z;
    }
    void operator+=(double a){
        this->re += a;
    }
    Comp operator+(Comp &z1){
        Comp z2(this->re + z1.re, this->im + z1.im);
        return z2;
    }
    void operator+=(Comp &z){
        this->re += z.re;
        this->im += z.im;
        }
    Comp operator*(double scalar){
        Comp z(this->re * scalar, this->im * scalar);
        return z;
    }
    void operator*=(double scalar){
        this->re *= scalar;
        this->im *= scalar;
    }
    Comp operator*(Comp &z1){
        Comp z2(this->re * z1.re - this->im * z1.im, this->re * z1.im + this->im * z1.re);
        return z2;
        }
    void operator*=(Comp &z1){
        //this->re = this->re * z1.re - this->im * z1.im;
        //this->im = this->re * z1.im + this->im * z1.re;
        Comp z2(this->re * z1.re - this->im * z1.im, this->re * z1.im + this->im * z1.re);
        *this = z2;
    }
    Comp operator^(int exp){
         Comp z;
         for(int i = 0; i <= exp; i++){
            double term = ncr(exp, exp - i) * pow(this->re, exp - i) * pow(this->im, i);
            switch(i % 4){
                case(0):{
                    z.re += term;
                    break;
                }
                case(1):{
                    z.im += term;
                    break;
                }
                case(2):{
                    z.re -= term;
                    break;
                }
                case(3):{
                    z.im -= term;
                    break;
                }
            }
         }
    return z;
    }
    Comp operator/(double scalar){
        Comp z(this->re/scalar, this->im/scalar);
        return z;
    }
    void operator/=(double scalar){
        this->re = this->re/scalar;
        this->im = this->im/scalar;
    }
    Comp operator/(Comp &z1){
        Comp z2 = z1.conj();
        z2 = (z2 * (*this)) / (z2.re * z2.re + z2.im * z2.im);
        return z2;
    }
    void operator/=(Comp &z1){
        Comp z2 = z1.conj();
        *this = (z2 * (*this)) / (z2.re * z2.re + z2.im * z2.im);

    }
};

#endif //COMPLEX_H
```

And here is the function where the code fails it's basically just a function which calculates f(z) = ax^n+bx^(n-1)+...+k for a given complex number 'z':

```
Comp f(Comp *poly, int deg, Comp z){
    Comp y;
    for(int i = 0; i <= deg; i++){
//here is the use of the overloaded operators
        y += (poly[i])*( z^(deg-i) );
    }
    return y;
}
```

My question is: how can i fix this and why have i been given this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `z^(deg-1)` returns an object of type `Comp`. That result gets passed to `operator*` which takes `Comp&`, i.e., it needs an **lvalue** of type `Comp`; `^` returns a temporary object, which is an **rvalue**. The fix is to change `operator*` (and all the rest of the operators) to take `const Comp&`. That way they can be called with lvalues and rvalues.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because the expression `( z^(deg-i) )` is a *temporary* `Comp` object, and those can be bound to non-constant references.

You need to make all your operator arguments `const` references. Like

```
Comp operator*(Comp const &z1){
```